# Знак вопроса в url от скрипта JS

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно, чтобы на сайте по классу менялись ссылки на новые. При использовании этого скрипта появляется знак вопроса вначале нового адреса. Как знак вопроса убрать и оставить новую чистую ссылку?

```js
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var i, links = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-link');
        for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].search = 'yandex.ru';
        }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо search поменять на href и добавить протокол

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var i, links = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-link');
        for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].href = 'https://yandex.ru';
        }});
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="lang-link">Link</a>
```